# Cython runtime exception when invoking method single arg with keyword

Tags: python, cython

I have python code that I convert to Cython.
I get a runtime exception on the following scenario:

```
class A:
   def foo(self, some_arg: int):
       pass
    
a = A()
some_arg = 5
a.foo(some_arg=some_arg)
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: foo() takes no keyword arguments
```

I found some relevant data [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/2881).
However:

1. The error is in runtime, not compile time as I would expect.
2. When adding to the setup.py file a compliler directive `always_allow_keywords=True` as suggested, I get corrupted .so files upon cythonizing the code. When I try to load them I get this error: `file xxx.so is too short`.

My Python version is: 3.7.2, cython version: 0.29.19.
The code is compiled with `gcc-linaro-aarch64` toolchain and run on a Linux based OS.

Comment: Your code would not work also in pure Python (with a slightly different error message) - it misses the `self`-argument in `foo`. Vote to close as typo.

Comment: thanks @ead , that's just because I white-washed the actual code. in Python in works. I will fix the code in the question

Comment: The code as it is now works for me. (cython 0.29.20 + python3.6)